# How to run tests smoothly in Leiningen project within Counterclockwise/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I'm a newbie with Clojure and Counterclockwise and I succeeded adding a Leiningen 2 project with ["Poor man's integration"](http://johnmichaelnewman.com/2011/04/13/poor-mans-integrating-leiningen-into-counterclockwise/) (External tools, linked from question [Using Clojure and Leiningen with IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389836/28482)).

My alternatives for running tests so far:

- From command line : lein test
- Running "lein test" with "Poor man's integration" (External tool)

These work pretty fine but I'm wondering whether there's some smoother alternative, for example showing the tests run like with JUnit etc?

Or with more general formulation, how to have fluent TDD flow with Counterclockwise?

Comment: FYI: The "Poor Man's Integration" link is dead now that Posterous Spaces is gone. That's probably OK given the focus of the question is "how do I get away from this?"

Comment: Good point, updated the link to a copy (that starts with "The information is out of date and needs to be updated, as CCW is much more mature now."). Got to check out CCW & tests at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje) with autotest in REPL seems to be worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative I found (with [clojure.test API](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.test-api.html)) was loading the test file in REPL (Alt+Cmd+S) and calling run-tests:

```
(run-tests)
```

With some trying, I can re-run the tests with my modifications by loading the modified file to REPL and calling run-tests again. (Works but isn't probably the final solution)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [cljunit](https://github.com/mikera/cljunit) as an interface between the JUNit runner in Eclipse and your Clojure tests.

Comment: Oh boy. Waaaaaay slow, poor output. Use lein test-refresh plugin instead. Output is better, and feedback is instant.